# How to rewrite an R loop taking averages of every 15 observations to same code but without a loop

Tags: r, loops, energy

I am dealing with a huge dataset (years of 1-minute-interval observations of energy usage). I want to convert it from 1-min-interval to 15-min-interval.

I have written a for loop which does this successfully (tested on a small subset of the data); however, when I tried running it on the main data, it was executing very slowly - and it would have taken me over 175 hours to run the full loop (I stopped it mid-execution).

The data to be converted to the 15-th minute interval is the kWh usage; thusly converting it simply requires taking the average of the first 15th observations, then the second 15th, etc. This is the loop that's working:

```
# Opening the file
data <- read.csv("1.csv",colClasses="character",na.strings="?")

# Adding an index to each row
total <- nrow(data)
data$obsnum <- seq.int(nrow(data))

# Calculating 15 min kwH usage
data$use_15_min <- data$use
for (i in 1:total) {
  int_used <- floor((i-1)/15)
  obsNum <- 15*int_used
  sum <- 0
  for (j in 1:15) {
    usedIndex <- as.numeric(obsNum+j)
    sum <- as.numeric(data$use[usedIndex]) + sum
  }
  data$use_15_min[i] <- sum/15
}
```

I have been searching for a function that can do the same, but without using loops, as I imagine this should save much time. Yet, I haven't been able to find one. How is it possible to achieve the same functionality without using a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try data.table:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(data)
n <- nrow(DT)
DT[, use_15_min := mean(use), by = gl(n, 15, n)]
```

### Note

The question is missing the input data so we used this:

```
data <- data.frame(use = 1:100)
```

Comment: Using this, the code for the whole data now runs in seconds! I am very grateful!

PS: yes, for privacy related reasons I was unable to share my input data, otherwise I would have

Comment: You can generate artificial data like I did in the Note.

Answer (score 1):

A potential solution is to calculate the running mean (e.g. using TTR::runMean) and then select every 15th observations. Here is an example:

```
df = data.frame(x = 1:100, y = runif(100))
df['runmean'] = TTR::runMean(df['y'], n=15)
df_15 = df[seq(1,nrow(df), 15), ]
```

I cannot test it, as I do not have Your data, but perhaps:

```
total <- nrow(data)
data$use_15_min = TTR::runMean(data$use, n=15)
data_15_min = data[seq(1, nrow(df), 15)]
```

Comment: I have not had the opportunity to test this code, as I started with the proposed one by G. Grothendieck and it worked. However, I am very grateful for the reply and suggestion!

PS: yes, for privacy related reasons I was unable to share my input data, otherwise I would have

Answer (score 0):

I would use `lubridate::floor_date` to create the 15-minute groupings.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- tibble(
  date = seq(ymd_hm("2019-01-01 00:00"), by = "min", length.out = 60 * 24 * 7),
  value = rnorm(n = 60 * 24 * 7)
)

df
#> # A tibble: 10,080 x 2
#>    date                  value
#>    <dttm>                <dbl>
#>  1 2019-01-01 00:00:00  0.182 
#>  2 2019-01-01 00:01:00  0.616 
#>  3 2019-01-01 00:02:00 -0.252 
#>  4 2019-01-01 00:03:00  0.0726
#>  5 2019-01-01 00:04:00 -0.917 
#>  6 2019-01-01 00:05:00 -1.78  
#>  7 2019-01-01 00:06:00 -1.49  
#>  8 2019-01-01 00:07:00 -0.818 
#>  9 2019-01-01 00:08:00  0.275 
#> 10 2019-01-01 00:09:00  1.26  
#> # ... with 10,070 more rows

df %>%
  mutate(
    nearest_15_mins = floor_date(date, "15 mins")
  ) %>%
  group_by(nearest_15_mins) %>%
  summarise(
    avg_value_at_15_mins_int = mean(value)
  )
#> # A tibble: 672 x 2
#>    nearest_15_mins     avg_value_at_15_mins_int
#>    <dttm>                                 <dbl>
#>  1 2019-01-01 00:00:00                  -0.272 
#>  2 2019-01-01 00:15:00                  -0.129 
#>  3 2019-01-01 00:30:00                   0.173 
#>  4 2019-01-01 00:45:00                  -0.186 
#>  5 2019-01-01 01:00:00                  -0.188 
#>  6 2019-01-01 01:15:00                   0.104 
#>  7 2019-01-01 01:30:00                  -0.310 
#>  8 2019-01-01 01:45:00                  -0.173 
#>  9 2019-01-01 02:00:00                   0.0137
#> 10 2019-01-01 02:15:00                   0.419 
#> # ... with 662 more rows
```

Comment: I didn't have the opportunity to test the code, as the first one I did (by G. Grothendieck) indeed worked, and very fast. But thanks a lot for the reply and the suggestion!